# Using call in JavaScript vs Returning by simple function

Tags: javascript, function, call

These are the 2 methods to calculate total amount based on object data:

**Snippet 1**

```js
var shoppingCart = (function(){
    function calculatePriceNow() {
        return this.price * this.amount;
    };
    return {
        calculatePrice : calculatePriceNow
    }
})();

var goods = {
       name : 'hammer',
       price: 199,
       amount : 2
};

var result = shoppingCart.calculatePrice.call(goods);
console.log(result);
```

**Snippet 2**

```js
var shoppingCart = (function(){
    function calculatePriceNow(obj) {
        return obj.price * obj.amount;
    };
})();

var goods = {
       name : 'hammer',
       price: 199,
       amount : 2
};

var result = shoppingCart.calculatePriceNow(goods);
console.log(result);
```

**Result 1:**

398

**Result 2:**

[image]

**My Query**

1. Why second snippet gives error instead of answer?
2. What is the importance of using 'call' in the first method? Cannot simple function also return the same answer?
3. What is advantage of call over *apply* and *bind* if same used in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to address each of your questions.

> Why second snippet gives error instead of answer?

Because, you are using an IIFE, yet you are return nothing. If you do not explicitly return something in javascript (in a function) it is implied to return undefined. Thus your error "cannot... of undefined". So you'd want to return that function, that you have inside of it.

> What is the importance of using 'call' in the first method? Cannot simple function also return the same answer?

The important of call (and apply) is the ability to "bind" the context. So, in your snippet 1 - do you see the references to `this`. Well, when you call the function with `call` - you are "binding" the context of `goods` to `this`. So, when you say `this.price`, you are saying `goods.price`. Because `call` enables you to do that.

> What is advantage of call over apply and bind if same used in this example?

Others might know the intricacies, but I believe `call` is fine in this context. IF, you were passing some arguments in addition to setting the "context" - like an array, then you'd use `apply`. The usage of `bind` returns a new function, so there is a memory cost there. It is like partial application - you give an argument, the context - and it returns a new function - waiting. I'd say in your usage, call is perfect. I'd like to hear what others think.

Comment: Thanks. Kindly vote up if you think question did make any sense! ;(

Answer (score 1):

> Why second snippet gives error instead of answer?

Your second snippet is throwing an error because you forgot to add this inside the IIFE:

```
return { calculatePriceNow : calculatePriceNow };
```

> What is the importance of using 'call' in the first method? Cannot simple function also return the same answer?

The importance of `call` is that it means you're using an **object-oriented** approach instead of a **functional** approach. Using `this` vs. using a parameter are both equally correct ways to accomplish the task. They only differ by their associated programming paradigm. In JavaScript, it's becoming much more popular to use the functional approach, using the parameter.

> What is advantage of call over *apply* and *bind* if same used in this example?

Using `apply` would be equally as good as `call` in this case, though `bind` would require an extra set of parentheses after you call it:

```
var result = shoppingCart.calculatePrice.bind(goods)();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to clear up things a bit.

```
<script>
    var shoppingCart = (function () {

        function calculatePriceNow() {
            return this.price * this.amount;
        };
        return {
            calculatePrice: calculatePriceNow
        }
    })();

    var goods = {
        name: 'hammer',
        price: 199,
        amount: 2
    };

    // will not work; Why? Because the function `calculatePrice` depends on their scope (`this`)
    var result = shoppingCart.calculatePrice(goods); 
    console.log(result);

    // will work; Why? We are calling the function giving it's scope explicitly using `call`
    var result = shoppingCart.calculatePrice.call(goods);
    console.log(result);

    // will work; Why? We are calling the function giving it's scope explicitly using `apply`
    var result = shoppingCart.calculatePrice.apply(goods);
    console.log(result);

    // How did it work with `call` and `apply`?
    // They are executing `calculatePrice` in the scope of the argument `goods` which we passed to the function
    // Doing so, the usage of `this` inside the function `calculatePrice` refer to the object `goods`

    // Difference between `call` and `apply`?
    // From MDN: 
    // The `apply()` method calls a function with with a given `this` value and `arguments` provided as array 
    // On the other hand, `call()` method calls a function with a given `this` value and `arguments` provided individually

</script>
```

**Notes**:

Will not work; Why? Because the function `calculatePrice` depends on its scope (`this`)

```
var result = shoppingCart.calculatePrice(goods); 
console.log(result);
```

Will work; Why? We are calling the function giving it's scope explicitly using `call`

```
var result = shoppingCart.calculatePrice.call(goods);
console.log(result);
```

Will work; Why? We are calling the function giving it's scope explicitly using `call`

```
var result = shoppingCart.calculatePrice.apply(goods);
console.log(result);
```

How did it work with `call` and `apply`?

They are executing `calculatePrice` in the scope of the argument `goods` which we passed to the function. Doing so, the usage of `this` inside the function `calculatePrice` refer to the object `goods`.

Difference between `call` and `apply`?

The [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method calls a function with with a given `this` value and `arguments` provided as array 
On the other hand, [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method calls a function with a given `this` value and `arguments` provided individually

**To the queries**:

> Why second snippet gives error instead of answer?

Like mentioned above, when we call like that the `scope` is that of the function, not of the 'argument'

> What is the importance of using 'call' in the first method? Cannot
>   simple function also return the same answer?

Simple answer would we that we are giving it `explicit scope` using `call`

> What is advantage of `call` over `apply` and `bind` if same used in this
>   example?

`call()`, `apply()` and `bind()` are part of all `function` object in JavaScript. The usage of it varies as mentioned above. 
The advantages over `call()` and `apply()` is the flexibility on calling a method (say with different arguments).