# Comparison of call, apply, bind in a simple example

Tags: javascript, function, scope, this, call

> This question compares the return by the 3 methods rather than comparing how this can be done easily by a normal IIFE function return.

This simple example shows comparison of results achieved with the scope binding methods, viz - call, apply, and bind.

**Snippet:**

```js
function printName() {
  return this.name;
}

var obj1 = { name: 'Peter' };
var obj2 = { name: 'John'};
var obj3 = { name: 'Richard' };

var result1 = printName.call(obj1);
var result2 = printName.apply(obj2);
var result3 = printName.bind(obj3);

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
console.log(result3);
```

**Results:**

[image]

**Query:**

1. What changes to make in program to get result as 'Richard' in 3rd case?
2. If call and apply do the same thing as in 1st and 2nd case what is importance of apply over bind OR when to use apply other than call?
3. Even if bind return function, shouldn't in console the function show some binding of obj3 with this function (Like obj3 as arguments)?

Comment: Can you explain how this is different from your previous question? [Using call in JavaScript vs Returning by simple function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39697000/using-call-in-javascript-vs-returning-by-simple-function) It seems like the differences were already discussed.

Comment: This question basically compares the 3 ways; earlier was the one which compared normal function with call method.

Comment: The first two questions are both answered in the answers to your previous question.

Comment: You can make `result3 == "Richard"` by calling it - `var result3 = printName.bind(obj3)();`

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: What console is that? Normally it should show that it's a bound function indeed.

Comment: Sir, this is a Chrome Browser console! Kindly check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three of your result vars are referencing functions hence these vars are functions themselves. When you use the bind method, you are assigning the printName function to be executed AFTER the fact whereas call and apply methods are run immediately. In order to get "Richard" returned from result3 you simply need to invoke it as a function like this: result3(); Attempting to run result1() or result2() the same way will show an error because those methods were applied on the fly and are not available as functions after the fact.

When this line is read:

```
var result1 = printName.call(obj1);
```

...then the printName function is run immediately and the value returned from that function is assigned to result1. Same for result2.

When this line is read:

```
var result3 = printName.bind(obj3);
```

...then the function itself is assigned to result3 and can be run by typing

```
result3();
```

So call and apply are used for getting a value returned whereas bind is used for getting a function returned.

With regard to call and apply, since you do not have any references inside any of your objects or prototype methods to the THIS keyword, you don't need to pass in a redefined THIS context. Call and Apply methods are generally best when you need to change context of a method belonging to another object. Look at this extended example of adding a new method to obj1:

```
obj1.sayHello = function() {
    console.log('Hello ' + this.name);
}

obj1.sayHello() //returns "Hello Peter"
```

If you want to use the sayHello method inside of obj1 to show data from obj2 then that is where you can use call or apply like this:

```
obj1.sayHello.call(obj2);  //returns "Hello John"
```

The big difference between call and apply is when you want to pass parameters into a function that exists in another object. So if we change the sayHello method on obj1 as follows:

```
obj1.sayHello = function(greeting) {
    console.log(greeting + ' ' + this.name);
};
```

The sayHello function now accepts a parameter. Once again if you call the function like this:

```
obj1.sayHello('Welcome'); //returns Welcome Peter
```

but if you want to use this method on obj2 then you would do it like this:

```
obj1.sayHello.call(obj2, 'Greetings'); //returns Greetings John
```

When you use the call method, you can pass in parameters using comma separated strings. You can also use apply in this same way except that you would need to pass in an array of values as parameters like this:

```
obj1.sayHello.apply(obj2, ['Happy Hump Day']); //returns Happy Hump Day John
```

I hope this helps to clear it up for you.

Cheers,
Jim